# Can I expect results using System.Random to be reproducible on all systems?

Tags: haskell, random

Given the same seed, will Haskell's System.Random give me the same results for all systems, processor architectures and Haskell versions? Is there a promise that this will hold in the future?

More specifically can I expect this to always (past and future) return the same list?

```
import System.Random
rs = randomRs (1, 2^31-1) (mkStdGen 1)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure no such promise was formulated anywhere, and there wouldn't have been a good reason either. If you want a reproducable chain, why don't you just roll your own PRNG? It seems sensible to have this local if you're basically using it as a fixed infinite list. You can even make it an instance of `RandomGen`, so it can otherwise be used in exactly the same way as the `System.Random` tools.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I can think of lots of good reasons to guarantee consistent random streams; also the discussion here is relevant: http://blog.ezyang.com/2011/05/haskell-not-pure-enough/

Comment: Unless the documentation says it does, it probably doesn't.  Especially with very large numbers or small numbers (or reals with a lot of precision) where different systems will round differently.  It's probably possible, but would have to be programmed with extra care and would probably use specialized number types designed for no loss of data.  I'm not an expert on scientific calculations or random number generators, though.

Comment: @jberryman there certainly are lots of applications where you need consistent random streams, but they all in a way contradict the very notion of randomness. So it wouldn't be reasonable to make this consistency a default guarantee; in fact I'd consider it harmful to have code which makes such easily-broken assumptions (e.g. if you change the order of a `split` operation) without explicitly saying so.

Comment: Thanks @leftaroundabout! Do you want to post your comments as an answer so that I can approve it?

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-random number generators are deterministic with respect to the value they are "seeded" with. This is why `mkStdGen` is a pure function. If you are really concerned, yes it is best not to rely on invariants not part of a library's specification. Practically I wish to show that in this case pseudo-randomness has nothing to do with it--the problem reduces to whether pure Haskell without machine-specific types evaluates the same on different platforms.

[StdGen](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random/docs/src/System-Random.html#StdGen) is *currently* implemented with Int32s. Of course from those fixed size integers other types of a data can be sampled, but the random number generator itself only uses machine-independent data types. According to the [Integer](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#t%3aIntegral) class source, rounding is also not left up to the machine (this is true with C integer types too). With fixnums, unlike flonums, there is both less compelling performance benefits from breaking standards, and much greater program correctness risks.

Taking a step back from StdGen in particular, strong cryptography requires a a strong standard of pseudo-randomness -- unintentional architecture-specific behavior would likely be a major security whole, while intentional architecture-specific behaviour basically amounts to writing, maintaining, and proving correct multiple generators. If the extra effort is worth it, it's probably worth advertising/documenting it too.

Lastly, there are many pseudo-random number generators on Hackage (System.Random isn't supposed to be the fastest or securest AFIAK) and I would be surprised if one targeting cryptographic uses didn't offer the invariants you want.

Comment: If there exists more than one secure PRNG in the world, system-specific PRNGs are not security holes.